# Could not get unknown property 'packageForR' for task '::processDebugResources' of type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

**Bugs**: I want to update Realm database from version 4.2.0 to 4.3.3, but after gradle sync, it will fail

**Goal**

Update Realm from 4.2.0 to 4.3.3

**Expected Results**

Gradle sync will success

**Actual Results**

Gradle sync failed with stacktrace:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':QuizApp:processDebugResources'.
Could not get unknown property 'packageForR' for task 
':QuizApp:processDebugResources' of type 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.
```

**Top level gradle file**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha01'

    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath "com.github.nullstress:DependencyAnalysisPlugin:1.0.3"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.2"
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'
}
  }
```

I Try cleaning gradle cache and stop the gradle daemon. Then retry the build. But the problem remains

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using **ButterKnife**, just remove ***ButterKnife gradle plugin***, and use the **annotationProcessor + implementation** version instead. See step bellow:

1. Remove `apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'` in gradle
2. Just use/add dependencies below in gradle instead:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
       annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
   }
   ```

Comment: cannot find symbol @Bind

Comment: Can u detail about it bro?

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem after gradle plugin update from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

In my case problem was caused by butterknife plugin, which are not compatible with gradle plugin newer than 3.0.1

Unfortunately I haven't solved this problem yet. I had to downgrade gradle plugin to 3.0.1.

And now I'm wating for newer version of butterknife plugin.

Update:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1201

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5731